# Using iOS SDK framework (Philips Hue) in tvOS application - linking issue

Tags: ios, tvos, apple-tv, philips-hue, xcode7.1beta

I've already developed an iOS App in Swift using the PhilipsHue SDK for iOS.
https://github.com/PhilipsHue/PhilipsHueSDK-iOS-OSX

Now I started developing a Philips Hue application for the new AppleTV (tvOS). I also used the PhilipsHue SDK for iOS and nearly finished the development. In simulator everything works fine.

Last week I got an AppleTV Developer Kit and tried to deploy my application on the AppleTV, but I got the following error:

```
ld: in /Users/xxx/Development/xxx/xxx/HueSDK_iOS.framework/HueSDK_iOS(PHPortalConfig.o), building for tvOS, but linking in object file built for iOS, for architecture arm64
```

Does anybody know, how to fix this?
I'm using Xcode Version 7.1 beta 3 (7B85)

Comment: It doesn't appear from the Hue documentation that TVOS is supported as a framework yet.  (And how could it be, publicly, since they'd still be under the non-disclosure like everyone else?)  You might just need to wait for Philips to produce one.  Alternatively, you might be able to use the C++ SDK at https://github.com/mzanetti/shine/tree/master/libhue.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I know that the current PhilipsHue SDK does not support tvOS. But what confuses me is the fact, that it's running perfectly in the ATV simulator, but not on the device.

Comment: I found this: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/firebase-talk/DJ8qZAvXgSc (other SDK, but same problem) Seems like in previous betas of Xcode 7.1 it was just a warning and sind 7.1 beta3 it's an error. But still don't know why it's running even without warning on the simulator :/

Comment: Well, it's presumably due to there being a very short distance between TVOS and iOS under the hood.  But as you discovered, no simulator should be relied upon to be 100% accurate at modeling a physical device.  The fact that your code runs on the simulator implies that it will probably also work on the device once Philips releases a TVOS framework, but you won't truly know until after Apple releases TVOS so that Philips can legally release their own code.